# Convert Datetime Format in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, datetime

Here is my datetime data in excel

```
3/10/2014  11:59:59 AM
```

And i want to convert it into like this in vb.net

```
  // I have a variable that contains the datetime like this

   Dim audit_date as DateTime = 3/10/2014 11:59:59 AM // and i want to convert this to the one below

   Output = 2014-03-10 11:59:59
```

also i want to remove that AM/PM

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use like this

```
Dim res As string=DateTime.Now.Tostring("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
```

Edit:

```
Dim res As string=Convert.ToDateTime("3/10/2014  11:59:59 AM").Tostring("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: im not referring to datetime.now i have a variable that i want to change the datetime format

Answer (score 0):

If you are converting DateTime to String

```
sDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

or

```
Dim timeFormat As String = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

SDate.ToString(timeFormat)
```

Comment: Im not referring to date.now

Comment: something like that? but actually i never encounter parseExact

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.90).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2